# Symfony 2 Multiple providers not working in secuirty.yml

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-2.7

I have multiple proivders users and admin so i have following security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\AdminUser: bcrypt
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
    providers:
        #in_memory:
         #   memory: ~
        admin_db:
            entity: { class: AppBundle\Entity\AdminUser, property: email  }


    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin_db:
            provider: admin_db
            anonymous: false
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login



            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            #http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            #form_login: ~


    access_control:
      - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

But when i try to access login page then i see this error

> This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times. Try
>   clearing your cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your firewall does not allow any anonymous access as specified with `anonymous: false`. That means your access control for login does not work. The 2 common ways to solve this are either taking the login rout out of the firewall or allowing anonymous access and then use access_controls to require a role.

If you want to move the login route out:

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        security: false

    admin_db:
        ...
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
```

It's important that the route `login_check` points to something inside your firewall. So basically anything but `/login` will work, e.g. `login/check`. In your controller you can create an empty action for this or you can point it to the same action as login.

The other solution would be even simpler in your case, as your `access_control` is already correct:

```
firewalls:
    admin_db:
        ...
        anonymous: ~
```

In your access control you allow anonymous access for login, but all other routes must have `ROLE_ADMIN`. So no other changes should be necessary.

Comment: @dbrumann.now i cant login .no error just redirect to login after entering crednetials

Comment: Do you have the profiler toolbar on the bottom of your page? If so, check if your username appears or `anon.` and click on the name. It should send you to the security tab which gives you more details. Alternatively look into the logs whether login worked or not. From what it looks I guess the `pattern: ^/*` is missing in your `admin_db` firewall.

Comment: @dbrumann.second method works fine.thanks a lot.also deleted cache.thanks for the nice solution as well as for explaination\